# dom-to-image library does not work with svg image

Tags: svg, snapshot

I have an SVG image element inside a div and I want to convert to png. So I use dom to image library toPng function and pass the div element to it. But I get a blank image as output.

Here is what the div looks like:

```
<div id="element">
<svg height="103" version="1.1" width="103" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.328125px;" viewBox="0 0 103 103" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.2.0</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"/>
<image x="1.5" y="38.41666666666667" width="100" height="26.166666666666664" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
href="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"/>
</svg> 
</div>
```

And here is my code that tries to take dom image:

```
domtoimage.toPng(node).then((dataUrl)=> {

var img = new Image();

img.onload = () => {
                    _view.localScreenshotSource = img.src;
                    observer.next(img.src);
                };
img.src = dataUrl;
})
```

Similar code with svg text works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong tag in HTML, Change image to img and try again